# Pymongo - How to add array to a list and read it

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

So I am pretty new with mongodb and I have been trying to figure out past hours on how to add a array to a list.

Currently my DB looks like

```
_id, email (string), listItems (list)
```

and what I have been trying to figure out is how to add a array to a list that I would have a output of etc

```
listItmes = [{'raffleid': 63, 'entry': 1}]
```

What I have been trying to do for now is:

```
db.test.update_one({
            'email': 'helloworld@testing.com'
        }, {
            '$set': {
                'totalNumber': 1,
                'listItmes': {'raffleid': 63, 'entires': entry + 1} #I would like to add up +1 everytime I update the value
            }
        }, upsert=False)
```

Whenever I run this code it doesn't seem to add any value to the listItems but does work to update the other values, (also I would need probably to read whats currently entries on listItems and add + 1 I believe?) What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respect to "I would like to add up +1 everytime I update the value" ..you can try something like this :

```
collection_sales.update_one(
    {'email': 'helloworld@testing.com' },
    { '$inc': { "listItmes.entires" :10 }}
    )
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/

Comment: Right! Instead of 10 it should be 1? However I do need to make sure before so the entires goes in to the correct given id IF there will be more key, values inside the array

Comment: @Thrillofit86 Yes...you can replace 10 by 1

Comment: I love you man! This was exactly what I was looking for and this even helped me with another problems that I was stuck on! Ohhhhhh! Thank you so so so much!